# How to create a form in a dll and have it show up in the taskbar?

Tags: delphi, dll

I create a dll and insert in form i compile it successfully.

I Need Help?

The Form caption does not show in windows task bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    protected
      procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
    end;

implementation

procedure TMyForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  ExStyle := ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
end;
```